# Package 'apple-gl' not found when installing gcc via spack

Tags: opengl, spack

I am trying to install gcc version 12.2.0 (as super user `$ sudo su`) using SPACK `$ spack install gcc@12.2.0`. Nothing happend but the following error message: `==> Error: Package 'apple-gl' not found`

How can I update or obtain this "apple-gl" package?

Btw, I do have opengl installed, but I can not update neither via anaconda nor spack the opengl library up to date

```
$ apt-cache search opengl

gir1.2-mutter-6 - GObject introspection data for Mutter

libcogl-common - Object oriented GL/GLES Abstraction/Utility Layer (common files)

libcogl-dev - Object oriented GL/GLES Abstraction/Utility Layer (development files)

libcogl-doc - Object oriented GL/GLES Abstraction/Utility Layer (documentation)

libcogl-pango-dev - Object oriented GL/GLES Abstraction/Utility Layer (development files)

libcogl-pango20 - Object oriented GL/GLES Abstraction/Utility Layer

...
```

Answer (score 0):

Could this be caused by using multiple versions of Spack and sharing the misc
cache directory? I have seen this when updating the Spack version.

You can clear the misc cache by running the command:

```bash
spack clean --misc-cache
```

I've been bitten by the misc cache a few times so I usually add a `misc_cache` entry to `config.yaml` and set the path to be version specific.